# Retargeting newlib for c++ chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, cortex-m, newlib

I am using arm-none-eabi toolchain with newlib to target a custom board with an ARM Cortex-M0+ (specifically the [MCU-on-eclipse](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc/releases) version of the toolchain). I am compiling/linking with `-nostartfiles` and `--specs=nano.specs` and have re-targeted stdout and stderr to USB and a serial port respectively. I have created implementations for most of the C system calls.

I am using the chrono library with two [custom clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Clock), the now() functions get RTC time or my systick timer. It seems like this mirrors the purpose of the standard steady_clock and system_clock and so I though I could try using them.

to do so I had to implement the gettimeofday syscall which I did

```
// returning a set time of one second just for testing
int _gettimeofday(struct timeval* tv, void* tz) {
    tv->tv_sec  = 1;
    tv->tv_usec = 255;
    return 0;
}
```

my main code is as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    HWInit();

    static std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int64_t count1 = t1.time_since_epoch().count();
    int64_t count2 = t2.time_since_epoch().count();

    printf("Time 1: %lld\n Time 2: %lld\n", count1, count2);
    for(;;){}
    return 0;
}
```

using the debugger I can see that both `steady_clock::now()` and `sysytem_clock::now()` call my _gettimeofday() function and both end up with the exact same time-point.

of course if I try to do the following I get multiple definition errors:

```
using SysClock = std::chrono::system_clock;

SysClock::time_point SysClock::now() noexcept {
    return SysClock::time_point( SysClock::duration(1983) );
}
```

So can I somehow overload the now() functions of the standard chrono clocks? or maybe the entire clock implementation with my own duration and rep typedefs that match the hardware better? I can overload new and delete for my embedded system (and should), so doing this for chrono would also be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [gccs libstdc++ chrono.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc#L52):

- `system_clock::now()` uses `gettimeofday(&tv, 0);` or `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);` or syscall. If `gettimeofday` works for you, that means it uses it.
- `steady_clock::now()` uses `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);`. So you should overload `clock_gettime` and handle `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` argument.
- There is no `_clock_gettime_r` function provided by newlib, as one in [`_gettimeofday_t`](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/reent/gettimeofdayr.c) that passes newlib's `struct reent` around. If you want to handle multithreading within newlib, it's good to write your own similar wrapper that handles `_reent->errno` value. But the bet would be to overload `_gettimeofday_r` function as you aim only at newlib.

Comment: looks like gettimeofday is the only one that works, which means my copy was compiled with `_GLIBCXX_USE_GETTIMEOFDAY` instead of `_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_REALTIME`. The reent structure doesn't have any indication of the type of clock requested so I would probably have to recompile libstdc++ to get clock_gettime() working. thanks for the links to code.

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_USE_GETTIMEOFDAY` affects `system_clock::now()`. Because `libstdc++` for `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is compiled without `_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_GETTIME_SYSCALL` you need to provide the definition of `extern "C" int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);`. The `clk_id` is exactly used to specify the clock...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change the behavior of `system_clock` and `steady_clock`, I recommend just writing your own custom clocks and using them.  That way you can better tailor them to your hardware and needs.  If you have some way to get the current time, creating a custom `chrono` clock to wrap that function is very easy.

```
class SysClock
{
public:
    // 500MHz, or whatever you need
    using period                    = std::ratio<1, 500'000'000>;
    using rep                       = long long;
    using duration                  = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point                = std::chrono::time_point<SysClcok>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        return time_point{duration{
            /*turn SysTick_getValue() into the number of ticks since epoch*/}};
    }
};
```

Now use `SysClock::now()` in your code instead of `system_clock::now()`.  This gives you `SysClock::time_point` and `chrono::durations` result from the subtraction of two `SysClock::time_point`s.

If you can turn your low-level "now" into a count of ticks against some epoch, and you can describe those ticks as a compile-time fraction of a second with `period`, then you're good to go.

Comment: This is what I am doing now, with my custom clocks in a header `sealChrono.h` (it is a pinniped based framework) that then includes chrono and date.h (awesome library btw!). I was just hoping/experimenting with making the framework more transparent to the user. Recompiling the standard library is a little out of scope though, so I will probably stick with this solution.